# Is code that is a value valid if it nothing is done with it? What is done with it?

Tags: javascript

Would this kind of code be correct:

```
"Hello world!";
```

The value is doing nothing. The value is not given to a variable and nothing is done with it. Is this syntactically valid? What happens in computer memory, is the value just assigned somewhere in memory and never accessed or does it just get skipped cause it isn't used?

Comment: It's the code equivalent of one hand clapping

Comment: And we use it for things: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: @j08691 I am a good one hand clapper

Comment: @epascarello tmi bud ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's valid, in that it doesn't cause an error. But, as you correctly point out, the line really accomplishes nothing useful.

A string primitive is created (which takes some memory) and then that primitive is immediately available to be removed from memory because there are no stored code paths to access it.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid code.

Any remotely sane compiler / JITter will completely drop it.

Comment: Or it uses it such as strict mode